# Advanced Filters on KendoGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, kendo-grid

I am currently working on adding advanced filter capabilities to Kendo Grid.
using these filters user should be able to filter List of values in a column.
User should be able to create these filters and persist them in the database some how.

Using Kendo's filter functionality, I was able to construct filter object and was able to filter the grid, The limitations with this approach is, Kendo UI only supports only two filters. The other limitation is length of the URL.

The other approach is to use Specification Pattern.

I am not sure if it's the right way to do it. Any inputs on how to implement this functionality?

Comment: Can you give some kind of code example of your problem?

Comment: It's much more of an architecture issue, than a code issue. like, How to design a filter that can be used to filter multiple columns with out passing the entire filter string as an URL.